# Authentication to LDAP Server

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I'm using LDAP module to allow user login through a LDAP Server. This is server configuration:

**Server Properties**

- sid = eng_ldap_server
- numeric_sid = 1
- name = Eng LDAP Server
- status = 1
- ldap_type = ad
- address = 10.10.72.202
- port = 389
- tls = 0
- followrefs = 0
- bind_method = 2
- basedn = Array ( [0] => dc=BMS,dc=ORVIETO )
- binddn = admin
- user_dn_expression = cn=%username,%basedn
- user_attr =
- account_name_attr =
- mail_attr =
- mail_template =
- picture_attr =
- unique_persistent_attr =
- unique_persistent_attr_binary = 0
- ldap_to_drupal_user =
- testing_drupal_username =
- testing_drupal_user_dn =
- grp_unused = 0
- grp_object_cat =
- grp_nested = 0
- grp_user_memb_attr_exists = 0
- grp_user_memb_attr =
- grp_memb_attr =
- grp_memb_attr_match_user_attr =
- grp_derive_from_dn = 0
- grp_derive_from_dn_attr =
- grp_test_grp_dn =
- grp_test_grp_dn_writeable =
- search_pagination = 0
- search_page_size = 1000

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of problems with the connection and authentication with the server until I change the bind dn format.

Maybe try something like this:

binddn = webwasher88@hnbwyo.com

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't answer the question? I had the same result for the configuration user51713 and I was not able to connect to the server. After I changed the BIND DN format  to what I showed it worked with no problems.

Comment: This looks like an answer to me. @SofiaA, sometimes short answers get flagged as "questionable". To a reviewer, asking questions in an answer can make it look more like a comment than an answer. 

There's also an issue with OP's question; it's vague so your answer can only guess at the problem instead fully answer the question; typically questions like this are flagged as "too broad" (there can be many sources of the problem, and we can't know for sure without access to OP's environment). If you have any further questions you can ask them on the Meta site.